# xmlstarlet how can I specify s specific class

Tags: xmlstarlet

This code successfully makes enabled="false for both lines below. 
How can I change the following so enabled = false for only the second line?

```
xmlstarlet ed --inplace --update '//ResultCollector/@enabled' --value 'false' "${scriptLocation}"


 <ResultCollector guiclass="SimpleDataWriter" testclass="ResultCollector" testname="Simple Data Writer" enabled="true">

 <ResultCollector guiclass="ViewResultsFullVisualizer" testclass="ResultCollector" testname="View Results Tree" enabled="true">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XPath allows specifying a specific xml element by order of appearance inside its parent:

```
--update '//ResultCollector[2]/@enabled'
```

The above expression selects all `ResultCollector` elements that appear as second under their parent for processing.

More generally, chances are your application will be safer selecting elements by an embedded information (such as a tag value) instead of by order:

```
--update '//ResultCollector[@guiclass="ViewResultsFullVisualizer"]/@enabled'
```

If it suits you, the above expression selects for processing all `ResultCollector` elements whose tag `guiclass` is `ViewResultsFullVisualizer`. In your example this also causes only the second `ResultCollector` to be updated as well.